# How can I plot a polynomial at a specified set of x values?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the following polynomial:

```
6.09125E15 - 1.12464E16*x^1 + 1.35607E16*x^2 + -1.73465E16*x^3 + 2.6004E16*x^4 - 
  2.65074E16*x^5 + 1.55669E16*x^6 + -5.1382E15 *x^7 + 8.90337E14*x^8 - 6.31447E13*x^9
```

for the following set of x values

> 0.10674, 0.11393 , 0.1216, 0.1298, 0.13854, 0.14788, 0.15784, 0.16847, 0.17982, 0.19194, 0.20487, 0.21867, 0.23341, 0.24913, 0.26591, 0.28383, 0.30295, 0.32336, 0.34515, 0.3684, 0.39322, 0.41972, 0.44799, 0.47818, 0.51039, 0.54478, 0.58148, 0.62066, 0.66247, 0.70711, 0.75475, 0.8056, 0.85987, 0.9178, 0.97964, 1.04564, 1.11609, 1.19128, 1.27154, 1.35721, 1.44865, 1.54625, 1.65042, 1.76162, 1.8803, 2.00698, 2.1422, 2.28653, 2.44058, 2.605,  2.78051, 2.96784, 3.16779, 3.38122, 3.60902, 3.85217, 4.1117, 4.38872, 4.6844

I also want to get the corresponding y values. How can this be done? Please suggest a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, but first we have to get rid of the "calculator" notation, e.g. `1.12464E16`.  Since it is only a few numbers, it can be done by hand, but here's an automated approach:

```
fcn = 6.09125E15 - 1.12464E16*x^1 + 1.35607E16*x^2 + -1.73465E16*x^3 
    + 2.6004E16*x^4 - 2.65074E16*x^5 + 1.55669E16*x^6 + -5.1382E15 *x^7 
    + 8.90337E14*x^8 - 6.31447E13*x^9 /.
  a__ exp_Symbol?(StringMatchQ[ToString[#], "E" ~~ __] &) :> 
    a 10^ToExpression[StringSplit[ToString[exp], "E"][[1]]]
(*
  6.09125*10^15 - 1.12464*10^16 x + 1.35607*10^16 x^2 
- 1.73465*10^16 x^3 + 2.6004*10^16 x^4 - 2.65074*10^16 x^5 
+ 1.55669*10^16 x^6 - 5.1382*10^15 x^7 + 8.90337*10^14 x^8 
- 6.31447*10^13 x
*)
```

With that, we can get the x and y pairs:

```
data = Block[{x = #}, {x, fcn}]& /@ yourdata
```

and plot it

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

Or, if you don't care about the y-coordinates,

```
DiscretePlot[fcn, {x, yourdata}]
```

[image]

Note, `yourdata` must be a list in both cases.

Comment: I was working with E16 etc as exponentials. You are correct that they are calculator notations,now I remember.

Comment: dear @Blackbird is there any way to get the list of y values in a .txt or .dat file

Comment: A variation: `Transpose[{x, fcn} /. x -> yourdata]`, which will be faster on large, packed arrays.

Comment: ya you can by using export as
`Export["texts.txt", eq /. x -> tt]` where eq is your equation and tt is the set of values.

Comment: @MichaelE2 likely, but I was point scrounging ... :)

Comment: I was too lazy/hurried to write it up as a separate answer.  My variation was `Block[{x = #}, Transpose @ {x, fcn}] &@ yourdata`, but switched it to `ReplaceAll`.  Variations might help future visitors.  Feel free to include them, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be shown using `Mesh`.

```
f[x_] := 6.09125 10^15 - 1.12464 10^16*x^1 + 
1.35607 10^16*x^2 + -1.73465 10^16*x^3 + 2.6004 10^16*x^4 - 
2.65074 10^16*x^5 + 1.55669 10^16*x^6 + -5.1382 10^15*x^7 + 
8.90337 10^14*x^8 - 6.31447 10^13*x^9

meshPts = {0.10674, 0.11393, 0.1216, 0.1298, 0.13854, 0.14788, 
0.15784, 0.16847, 0.17982, 0.19194, 0.20487, 0.21867, 0.23341, 
0.24913, 0.26591, 0.28383, 0.30295, 0.32336, 0.34515, 0.3684, 
0.39322, 0.41972, 0.44799, 0.47818, 0.51039, 0.54478, 0.58148, 
0.62066, 0.66247, 0.70711, 0.75475, 0.8056, 0.85987, 0.9178, 
0.97964, 1.04564, 1.11609, 1.19128, 1.27154, 1.35721, 1.44865, 
1.54625, 1.65042, 1.76162, 1.8803, 2.00698, 2.1422, 2.28653, 
2.44058, 2.605, 2.78051, 2.96784, 3.16779, 3.38122, 3.60902, 
3.85217, 4.1117, 4.38872, 4.6844};
```

The plot.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0.10674, 4.6844}, Mesh -> {meshPts}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The $y$ values can be computed as follows.

```
f /@ meshPts
```

This can be shown on the plot using `GridLines`, although the points appear to be very close for the most part.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0.10674, 4.6844}, Mesh -> {meshPts}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
Axes -> False, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {meshPts, f /@ meshPts}]
```

[image]